# How can I find this limit? $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{x\csc(2x)}{3\cos(5x)}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{x\csc(2x)}{3\cos(5x)}\right)$$

My attempt was just turning csc to 1/sin, how can I solve this

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle x\cdot \csc(2x)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot{\frac{2x}{\sin(2x)}}$

Comment: after that do I flip 2x/sin2x ?

Comment: You can do it...

Comment: @method, $\lim\limits_{t \to 0}\tfrac{t}{\sin t }=\lim\limits_{t \to 0}\tfrac{\sin t}{t} = ?$ and $\cos(0)=?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for $x$ reaching $0$ $\sin {x} = x$

then

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac {x}{\sin{x}} = 1$$

$$\lim_{x\to0} \cos {x} = 1$$

So your limit is equal to $\frac{1}{6}$ if I'm not mistakening

Comment: The limit of $sin(x)$ as $x\to 0$ is not $x$.

Comment: Isn't it ? Maybe you can explain a little bit where I'm mistakening instead of just denying ?

Comment: Ok, what is the value of the limit? It has to be a unique real number, but $x$ is variable.

Comment: ok, it's a matter of formalism then, I'll edit that !

Comment: The limit is 0, so then what do you do in the second line?

Comment: I meant, when x is very small, sin (x) tends to be equal to x (according to taylor series), then you can simplify x/sin(x) to be 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19424/discussion-between-james-mitchell-and-babounet).

Comment: Sure, I'd really like to understand where mmy reasonning's failling.

Comment: @Babounet $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x = 0$. What you are saying is probably an approximation of $\sin x$ near zero ( ie, if $x$ is close to 0, then $\sin x \approx x$)